# how to create stacked bar graph with custom width based on X-values in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, bar-chart

I have an assignment where I need to generate a graph similar like the image below in python.
This chart consisted of 3 variables.

Working time [h] in X-axis.

Electric consumption[kW] and Gas [kg] in Y-axis STACKED

Is it possible to generate a chart similar like the below picture using matplotlib ,or with other libraries? (seaborn, altair, plotnine)

**EDIT:**

Is it possible to also generate a table below the graph, similar to the table below?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved my own question while creating this question :) .
Although this answer still cannot generate a table below the graph.

But here you go, I hope it can help someone who also have a similar problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Bar's starting x-point 
xPoint = [0, 850, 1100,1220, 1300, 1500]
# Values
Power = [850, 500, 150, 500, 400,1100]
Vapor = [750, 850, 300, 350, 200, 300]

# the width of the bars
width = [850,250,120,80,200,500]
# Bar Color's scheme
color1 = ['#E02E15','#E9C430','#3BB273','#456990','#8491A3','#505168']
color2 = ['#EF6958','#F0D670','#70CF9D','#7598BD','#ABB3BF','#80819D']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bar1 = ax.bar(xPoint, height= Power, width=width, align='edge', color=color1)
bar2 = ax.bar(xPoint, height= Vapor, width=width, align='edge', color=color2, bottom=Power)
ax.set_xlabel("Total hour[h]", fontname="MS Gothic", fontsize=16)            # https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text
ax.set_ylabel('Power Consumption＋Gas', fontname="MS Gothic", fontsize=16)
ax.set_title('Total Consumption Graph', fontname="MS Gothic", fontsize=20)

ax.bar_label(bar1, label_type='center')
ax.bar_label(bar2, label_type='center')
ax.bar_label(bar2)


plt.show()
```